# difference between String() and \() while you want to convert other types into string in swift

Tags: swift

When I want to convert other types into a string, I can use explicit transformation: string() and implicit transformation print(\()), right?

But I get a unwanted answer when I use \() while I'm printing my answer, and here is the picture, do you know why it is?

[image]

here is my code:

```
import Foundation
let a = "hello"
let b = String(a.characters.reversed())
print(b)
print("\(a.characters.reversed())")
let c = 0.9
print("\(c)")
```

Comment: *"a unwanted answer"* - tell me more please.

Comment: I mean that a and b should have same result when I print them, but when I print b, it gets "ReversedCollection..." .

Comment: It must be the same as the question "Difference between String interpolation and String initializer in Swift", thank you a lot